# How to scale push notifications to 60k concurrent users

Tags: azure, azure-functions, signalr, azureservicebus

I have 50-60k online users who are using our Chrome extension. Currently, we were using a pull mechanism to update the notifications. Now we are planning to move from pull to push to reduce the load from the API Servers.

We thought of instead using our own Signal R server we can utilize the Azure Signal R service but when I reviewed the pricing, 1 unit has only 1000 concurrent users which is $60 per unit. if I choose the premium tier for autoscaling.

Mostly the connections will be idle until the admin sends the notifications, It's a B2B setup. Now the problem is if I need to support 50k concurrent users it is going to cost $3000 (50 * 60) in one region which is huge for us. We have set up the autoscale for cost management

1. Autoscale only office hours and then scale down. The default will be 5
2. Scale when the server load is more than 70%

The second approach can be to use a Service bus or Redis as a backplane,
Signal R can be scaled on app services or virtual machines. all the platform management we have to do, which we were avoiding. But after seeing the below numbers, I amo more aligned with this.

.NET Threadpool and ASP.NET Settings

The maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU setting specifies how many simultaneous requests ASP.NET allows per CPU. This setting is different depending on the size of the virtual machine configured.

If 1 VM can support 18000 concurrent requests, it's making more sense to align with this and scale the boxes according to the load.

[image]

Any other suggestions?